# ¿Se puede usar sizeof dentro de una funcion para calcular el tamaño de un array?

Tags: c++, funciones, sizeof

No comprendo porque al tratar de calcular el tamaño dentro de la funcion size retorna 1 y al hacerlo desde el main, si me retorna el tamaño normal de 5.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int size(int A[]){

    int _size=sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    return _size;
}

int main(){
    int A[5];

    cout<<"Tamaño de A(FuncionSize): "<<size(A)<<endl;
    cout<<"Tamaño de A(Normal)"<<sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0])<<endl<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

´´´

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que en C los arrays se pasan por referencia. Es decir, cuando llamas a la función `size(A)`, *no se está copiando* el array completo al interior de la función, sino tan sólo *la dirección* en la que el array está guardado.

Esto puedes verificarlo porque si dentro de la función alteras por ejemplo `A[0]`, verás que el array del programa principal también resulta alterado ¡porque sólo hay un array! No hay una copia.

Esto implica que cuando haces `sizeof(A)` el resultado es diferente según dónde lo hagas:

- En el programa principal `A` es un array de 5 elementos, cada uno de ellos de tipo `int` por lo que `sizeof(A)` te dará como resultado `5*sizeof(int)`
- En la función `A` es una referencia al array del programa principal. Tales referencias son en realidad punteros. Por tanto `sizeof(A)` te devolverá el tamaño del puntero. Habitualmente el tamaño de un puntero suele coincidir con el tamaño de un entero (puesto que en el fondo un puntero es un número entero, que representa la dirección de memoria en la que está otro dato). Por esto al dividir por `sizeof(A[0])` te sale 1, aunque esto es casi  una casualidad. Si el tamaño del puntero fuese 64 bits, mientras que el tamaño del entero fuese 32, tu función `size()` habría retornado 2.

Y por si te lo estás preguntando, **no**, no hay forma de saber desde la función cuántos elementos tiene el array que le has pasado como parámetro. Todo lo que la función recibe es la dirección de memoria donde comienza el array, pero no la dirección en la que termina. Es por esto que la mayoría de funciones C que reciben como parámetro algún tipo de array (por ejemplo, un buffer), requieren un parámetro adicional, habitualmente llamado `size`, donde se les pasa cuántos elementos tiene ese array. Sin ir mas lejos, `main()` recibe dos parámetros: `argc` y `argv`, siendo el segundo un array de cadenas y el primero un entero que le dice cuántos elementos tiene el array.

Comment: Me sirvio mucho, tanto la pregunta como la respuesta
Muchas gracias. Saludos.